# Power BI - Calculating average with multiple filters

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, measure

I want to calculate the average of monthly values, based on the filtered names and months. I have a table like this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYFeZ.png)

It should be the average of the values of the two month periods of the workers. Like John´s september average is 13+29/2 = 21. John´s october average is 42+32/2 = 37, and so on...

I tried several formulas based on this one:
CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Values]),
CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[Month]) && 'Table' [Name]) , and it didn´t work out:

Can you help me, how could I modify the formula to return the expected values? Or even suggest an other formula.
I would be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result when it is done as shown in the image to give the average value from the value part in the stacked bar chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

calculate(AVERAGE('Table'[Values]),all('Table'[Period]))

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately as I tried it, it didnt return the average values... ´